# PHP & HTML - Not able to get Text field value

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP, I have mentioned below my HTML and PHP codes. I am not able to get the textbox (I have mentioned below the textboxes names) value to PHP. I have mentioned below both HTML and PHP codes.

Text boxes which I am not able to access:

```
Section <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_sec" id="f_b1_s1_sec">
Content <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_con" id="f_b1_s1_con"><br><br> 
Para <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_para" id="f_b1_s1_para">
```

HTML Code:

```
<form name="input" action="footer_view.php" onsubmit="return criteria('f', 3)" method="post">
<h1><center><u><font color="Maroon">Footer Issues</font></u></center></h1>
<ul id="tabs">
<li id="tab1"><a href="f_sec.html">Section</a></li>
<li id="tab2"><a href="f_link.html">Link</a></li>
<li id="tab3"><a href="www.google.co.in">Content</a></li>
<li id="tab4"><a href="www.google.co.in">alignment</a></li>
<li id="tab5"><a href="www.google.co.in">Function</a></li>
<li id="tab6"><a href="www.google.co.in">Others</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
Select an Issue <br> <select name="f_d" id="f_d" onchange='drop("f", 3)'>
<option value=00>Select</option>
<option value=01>A section is missing</option>
<option value=02>Section is not aligned properly</option>
<option value=03>A section overlaps another section</option>
</select>

<div id="f_b1" style="display:none;">
Environment <br> <select name="f_b1_s1_env" id="f_b1_s1_env" onchange="envDrop(1, 1)">
<option value="ENG">ENG</option>
<option value="DEV" selected>DEV</option>
<option value="STAGE">STAGE</option>    
<option value="WWWTMP">WWWTMP</option>
<option value="LIVE">LIVE</option>
</select>

&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_sp1" id="f_b1_s1_sp1"         onClick="envSpecific(1,1)">Specific
<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_env1" id="f_b1_s1_env1">ENG
<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_env2" id="f_b1_s1_env2" disabled>DEV
<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_env3" id="f_b1_s1_env3" disabled>STAGE
<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_env4" id="f_b1_s1_env4" disabled>WWWTMP
<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_env5" id="f_b1_s1_env5" disabled>LIVE

<br><input type="radio" name="f_b1_s1_brw" id="f_b1_s1_brw" onClick="get(1,1,1)"     value="browser">Browser
<input type="radio" name="f_b1_s1_brw" id="f_b1_s1_dvc" onClick="get(1,1,2)"     value="device">Device
<input type="radio" name="f_b1_s1_brw" id="f_b1_s1_both" onClick="get(1,1,3)"     value="both">Both
<div id="f_b1_s1_brww1" style="display:none;">
<select name="f_b1_s1_brow[]" id="f_b1_s1_brow" multiple>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="IE 10">IE 10</option>
<option value="IE 9">IE 9</option>
<option value="IE 8">IE 8</option>
<option value="IE 6">IE 6</option>
<option value="FF 25">FF 25</option>
<option value="FF 24">FF 24</option>
<option value="FF 22">FF 22</option>
<option value="CHROME">CHROME</option>
<option value="MAC SAFARI 6.0">MAC SAFARI 6.0</option>
<option value="MAC FF25">MAC FF25</option>
<option value="MAC CHROME">MAC CHROME</option>
<option value="OPERA">OPERA</option>
<option value="IPAD">IPAD</option>
<option value="SOGDU">SOGDU EXPLORER</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="f_b1_s1_sp2" id="f_b1_s1_sp2">Specific
</div>

<div id="f_b1_s1_brww2" style="display:none;">
<select name="f_b1_s1_dvc1" id="f_b1_s1_dvc1">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<option value="IOS 7">IOS 7</option>
<option value="IOS 6">IOS 6</option>
<option value="IOS 6 & 7">IOS 6 & 7</option>
<option value="AND 2.3">AND 2.3</option>
<option value="AND 4.0">AND 4.0</option>
<option value="AND 2.3 & 4.0">AND 2.3 & 4.0</option>
<option value="BB">BB</option>
</select>
</div>

<br><br>Pre-Condition<br><select name="f_b1_s1_pc[]" id="f_b1_s1_pc" multiple><br>
<option value="User with no saved address">User with no saved address</option>
<option value="User with only billing address">User with only billing address</option>
<option value="Partial User">Partial User</option>
<option value="Return User">Return User</option>
<option value="User with billing, default shipping and other address">User with billing,     default shipping and other address</option>
</select>
<br><br>Test Data&nbsp;&nbsp;</br><textarea rows="3" cols="25" name="f_b1_s1_td"     id="f_b1_s1_td"></textarea>
<br><br>Section &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_sec"     id="f_b1_s1_sec">
<br><br>Content &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      <input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_con"     id="f_b1_s1_con"><br><br> 
Para&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_para"     id="f_b1_s1_para">
<br><br>Additional Observation<br><textarea rows=3 cols=25 name="f_b1_s1_ao"     id="f_b1_s1_ao"></textarea>
<br><br>Pages<br><select name="f_b1_s1_pg[]" id="f_b1_s1_pg" multiple><br>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Homepage">Homepage</option>
<option value="Profile">Profile</option>
<option value="Shopping Cart">Shopping Cart</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="f_b1_s1_pg_hid" name="f_b1_s1_pg_hid" value="Homepage">
<br><br>Reference Site with same behavior&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input     type="text" name="f_b1_s1_rs1" id="f_b1_s1_rs1">
<br><br>Reference Site with not same behavior &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="f_b1_s1_rs2" id="f_b1_s1_rs2">
<br/>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
$tx0 = $_POST['f_b1_s1_sec'];
$tx1 = $_POST['f_b1_s1_con'];
$tx2 = $_POST['f_b1_s1_para'];
//code for three fields
if ($tx1 == NULL && $tx2 == NULL)
{
    if ($tx0 != NULL)
    {
        $sec_sum = $tx0." section is not displayed.";
        $sec_step = "Go to the bottom of the page and look for the ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_act = $tx0." section is not displayed.";
        $sec_exp = $tx0." section should be displayed.";
        $sec_ref1 = $tx0." section is displayed.";
        $sec_ref2 = $tx0." section is not displayed.";
    }
}
if ($tx0 != NULL && $tx1 != NULL)
{
    if ($tx2 == NULL)
    {
        $sec_sum = $tx1." of ".$tx0." section is not displayed.";
        $sec_step = "Go to the bottom of the page and look for the ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_act = $tx1." of ".$tx0." section is not displayed.";
        $sec_exp = $tx1." of ".$tx0." section should be displayed.";
        $sec_ref1 = $tx1." of ".$tx0." section is displayed.";
        $sec_ref2 = $tx1." of ".$tx0." section is not displayed.";
    }
}
if ($tx0 != NULL && $tx1 != NULL)
{
    if ($tx2 != NULL)
    {
        $sec_sum = $tx1." is not displayed in ".$tx2." para in ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_step = "Observe the ".$tx2." para in ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_act = $tx1." is not displayed in ".$tx2." para in ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_exp = $tx1." should be displayed in ".$tx2." para in ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_ref1 = $tx1." is displayed in ".$tx2." para in ".$tx0." section";
        $sec_ref2 = $tx1." is not displayed in ".$tx2." para in ".$tx0." section";
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your html, I'm not seeing a /form tag. Is there one there, below the code you posted?

Comment: your form is not closed u need to close it as </form> after all the HTML fields are rendered.

Comment: How do you know that you don't get them, did you try echoing them or `print_r($_POST)`?  Also, what is `criteria()`

Comment: @larsAnders - Yes form has close tag and I am able to get all the form values except these three text fields.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - If I use "array_key_exists("f_b1_s1_sec", $_POST);" it is give 1 as output, but when I try to access the field using "$_POST["f_b1_s1_sec"];", it does not give any output.

Comment: Maybe it's happening in `criteria()` before the data is sent to PHP?

Comment: I'm seeing a few other HTML issues, FYI - in the textarea just above these inputs there is a malformed </br> tag. Also, in the select with name="f_d", all of the option values are missing double quotes. And in the textarea immediately following, there are missing double quotes around the attributes: rows=3 cols=25

Comment: @AbraCadaver, when I tried print "print_r($_POST)"; out is displaying as below. There also "[f_b1_s1_sec] => [f_b1_s1_con] => [f_b1_s1_para] =>" keys are blank even though I give value in these fields.

"Array ( [f_d] => 01 [f_b1_s1_env] => DEV [f_b1_s1_brw] => browser [f_b1_s1_brow] => Array ( [0] => IE 8 ) [f_b1_s1_dvc1] => Select [f_b1_s1_td] => [f_b1_s1_sec] => [f_b1_s1_con] => [f_b1_s1_para] => [f_b1_s1_ao] => [f_b1_s1_pg] => Array ( [0] => All ) [f_b1_s1_pg_hid] => Homepage [f_b1_s1_rs1] => [f_b1_s1_rs2] => )"

Comment: @AbraCadaver has the right question - can you post the Javascript for the function criteria()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a form close tag after all of your input fields:

```
</form>
```

Also, I'm hoping that this php code is in the file given in your action attribute. So the above php code should be in footer_view.php which is the file that the form values are posted to when the form is submitted.

Comment: Hi, I closed the form and I am able to get all the values except these three fields.